# Why is getData method in ngOnInit is showing error

Tags: angular

I added a method to ngOnInit and it's throwing the error
1.Cannot find name getData
2.Missing Semicolon

Why is it showing that error.

```js
    import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        
        @Injectable()
        export class DataService implements OnInit {
          data: {}[] = [
            {
              name: 'John Doe',
              email: 'johndoe@example.com'
            },
            {
              name: 'Jane Doe',
              email: 'janedoe@example.com'
            },
            {
              name: 'Mary Doe',
              email: 'marydoe@example.com'
            }
          ];
          constructor() { }
        
          ngOnInit() {
        
            getData() {
              return this.data;
            }
        
          }
        }
```

Comment: Just remove the last } and move it before getDate()

Answer (score 2):

You dont use ngOnInit in service. Its only for components. Services are just es6 classes with some magic for angular to use in their dependency injection system.

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class DataService {
      data: {}[] = [
        {
          name: 'John Doe',
          email: 'johndoe@example.com'
        },
        {
          name: 'Jane Doe',
          email: 'janedoe@example.com'
        },
        {
          name: 'Mary Doe',
          email: 'marydoe@example.com'
        }
      ];
      constructor() { }



      getData() {
        return this.data;
      }


    }
```